# Geany Java support on Windows

Tags: java, autocomplete, code-snippets, geany

I just installed `Geany` and want to do `Java` programming using `Geany` on `Windows`. My questions are:

1. Does `Geany` or any of its plugins support `Java` code completion? and Where can I find/set up it in `Geany`?
2. Does `Geany` support `Java` code snippets, and how do I define my own snippets?
3. Does `Geany` support other `Java` code editing features, e.g. auto formatting, auto imports, statement auto-complete etc.

many thanks

Comment: Did you do any research on your behalf? Quick tour on some search engine gave me [this](http://kevinfelisilda.blogspot.de/2012/07/how-to-compile-java-programs-in-geany.html) to answer point 1.

Comment: Please split your question into separate atomic ones.